Determining Distribution for Conditional Probability
I have that the conditional probability density of $Y|X$ is as such
$f_{Y | X} \propto x^{y - 1}(1-x)^{n-y-1}\alpha^{n-y}\beta^{y}$
where $\alpha, \beta$ are constants in $(0, 1)$, $x$ is a random variable in $(0, 1)$, and $y = 0, 1, 2, ..., n$.
I want to determine what distribution this conditional probability density belongs to. My immediate thought was the geometric distribution, but this seems impossible. If I shed the terms that aren't a function of $y$ then I get
\begin{align*}
f_{Y | X} &\propto x^{y}(1-x)^{-y}\alpha^{-y}\beta^{y} \\
&= (x\beta)^{y}((1-x)\alpha)^{-y} \\
&= \left(\frac{x\beta}{(1-x)\alpha}\right)^{y}
\end{align*}
but I can't recall any distributions that match that either.
I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Isn't that a geometric distribution with parameter $p=(x\beta)/((1-x)\alpha)$?

If it is a density, i.e. from a continuous distribution, then perhaps an exponential distribution with parameter  $\lambda= -\log_e \left(\dfrac{x\beta}{(1-x)\alpha}\right)$

But you say $y = 0, 1, 2, ..., n$, so not a continuous distribution, i.e. you do not have a density.  If $y$ cannot exceed $n$, then you have a probability mass function from a truncated geometric distribution.

That algebraic rearrangement is a good start. Perhaps writing $q=x\beta/((1-x)\alpha),$ which expresses the conditional probability mass function of $y$ more simply as $q^y$ (for integers $0\le y\le n$), will help you see the answer.  Among the many possible characterizations it can be viewed as a form of a truncated Geometric distribution.
